# String to datetime conversion in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime-format

Is it possible to convert 'OCT-20' to '2020/10/01' in sql server. I tried the following cases without any luck.

```
select convert(date, 'OCT-20',103)
```

----Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
alter table MyTable alter column [period] date
```

----Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I am using sql server 2016.

Comment: OCT-19 What should be the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* we assume that the value is always in the format `MMM-yy` then you could do this:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(date,'01-' + StringDate,106)
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Of course, this has 2 flaws.

1. The date uses a 2 digit year, so SQL Server *could* assume the wrong century
2. It'll only work if the `LOGIN` is using an English based language, otherwise it'll fail.

The *real* solution is to fix your design; never store date (and time) values in a `varchar`, and when ever you do use a `varchar` for a date (such as a literal in a `WHERE`) use an unambiguous format such as `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`.

Comment: I cannot change the design as I am getting the data from the client. But your solution solves my problem.

Comment: If it solves the problem, @AjayMahato , please do mark it as the solution, as that indicates to future users that the answer was helpful. Many thanks.

Comment: @AjayMahato You and your organization should have a very **SERIOUS** discussion with client about Y2K and why 2 digit years are always a bad idea. And using a language-specific format is another bad idea.

Comment: I'm "looking forward" to the SQL Server 2.05K "bug" @SMor ;)

Comment: @SMor I had raised this concern before but the client refuses to change the format citing that it has already been deployed with their products all over the world and changing it is not worth the effort.

Comment: Time to move provider then, before you suffer the 2.05K bug I mentioned above, @AjayMahato .It's only 30 years away (which really isn't that long).